# Problema con if else

Tags: javascript

Al ejecutar el código el resultado siempre imprime la sentencia de `else`, así sea la condición de `if` verdadera.

```js
function Calculate()
{
    var planetsList = {
        "Mercurio": 0,
        "Venus": 0,
        "Tierra": 1,
        "Marte": 2,
        "Júpiter": 16,
        "Saturno": 17,
        "Urano": 14,
        "Neptuno": 2,
        "Plutón": 1
    }

    var num = document.form.elements["number"].value;
    var res = "";

    for(var planet in planetsList) {
        if(num <= planetsList[planet]) {
            res += planet + ": " + planetsList[planet] + "<br/>";
        }
        else {
            res = "No hay planetas que contengan una cantidad de satélites igual o mayor a la especificada.";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Objetos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form name="form" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ingrese el número de satélites:</th>
                        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="number" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="Calculate()"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que tu condición es incorrecta. Según yo observo es verdadero para algunos elementos de tu array pero tu **sobreescribes la respuesta final** cuando un solo elemento no cumple la condición.

Debería mover tu validación fuera del `for` y solo indicar el mensaje de "no hay planetas..." si es que la respuesta sigue vacía al finalizar tu `for`

```js
function Calculate()
{
    var planetsList = {
        "Mercurio": 0,
        "Venus": 0,
        "Tierra": 1,
        "Marte": 2,
        "Júpiter": 16,
        "Saturno": 17,
        "Urano": 14,
        "Neptuno": 2,
        "Plutón": 1
    }

    var num = document.form.elements["number"].value;
    var res = "";

    for(var planet in planetsList) {
        
        if(num <= planetsList[planet]) {
            res += planet + ": " + planetsList[planet] + "<br/>";
        }
    }
    
     if(res == "") {
            res = "No hay planetas que contengan una cantidad de satélites igual o mayor a la especificada.";
        }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Objetos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form name="form" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ingrese el número de satélites:</th>
                        <td><input type="text" size="2" name="number" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="Calculate()"/></td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay un pequeño problema en la lógica cuando se arma la string html a presentar.

Efectivamente se están listando los planetas, pero como el bucle recorre todo el arreglo, en algún momento se cruza con un planeta que no cumple y en esa linea de código se reemplaza todo el contenido del string. El resultado es que al final del bucle se muestra solo el mensaje de que no existen planetas que cumplen la condición, excepto en el caso que el último del arreglo si cumpliera.

la solución es condicionar el bucle, si previamente no hubo planetas, se escribe, de lo contrario se omite.

```js
function Calculate()
{
var planetsList = {
    "Mercurio": 0,
    "Venus": 0,
    "Tierra": 1,
    "Marte": 2,
    "Júpiter": 16,
    "Saturno": 17,
    "Urano": 14,
    "Neptuno": 2,
    "Plutón": 1
}

var num = document.form.elements["number"].value;
var res = "";
var cumplen = 0;

for(var planet in planetsList) {
    if(num <= planetsList[planet]) {
        res += planet + ": " + planetsList[planet] + "<br/>";
        cumplen++;
    }
}
if(cumplen == 0) { res += "No hay planetas que contengan una cantidad de satélites igual o mayor a la especificada.";}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: No es necesario agregar otra variable para llevar un "contador".